# The css of my project is getting harmed after refreshing the ' update asset' page'

Tags: css, reactjs, mern

I am working on a CRUD(MERN) project and facing a very weird issue. The css is getting harmed only after refreshing the 'Update Asset' page and to get things to normal again, I have to refresh the "Asset List" page. The image of the 'Update Asset' page, just have a look at the navbar and also see the Asset List page.
**NOTE**:- The data in the input fields do not get affected. The form also remains unaffected because I have picked it up from a library.
[This is the Asset List page, the whole table has got affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VXAY.jpg)
[Have a look at the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx3kj.jpg)

These images will show how the actual project should look.[This is the perfect page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVAc2.jpg)
[This is the asset list page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RfNv.jpg)